# Spring Boot Security - Every endpoint is 403 forbidden and Spring logs a BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

My application sends a list of servers as json from my database (endpoint "/server/list"). It works fine without all the authentication stuff. I implemented everything from this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxqlJblhzfI&list=PLxS-v6jO4Fxv3Z4fRSFSPZUiGaSyx3Olh&index=33&ab_channel=Amigoscode) into my application and I can register a user without any problems, when I send a postman request:

http://localhost:8080/auth/register

```
{
    "firstname": "Mary",
    "lastname": "Hyne",
    "email": "maryhyne@google.com",
    "password": "asdf"
}
```

A JWT Token is generated and I use them in the Authorization header of my other request:

http://localhost:8080/server/list (Authorization -> Bearer Token)

But I always get a 403 Forbidden answer. There is also no helpful Exception. Only the message "Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)". So I dont know what is wrong. Since I cant even grasp what the error might be, I post the most appearently important code. I will spare out the server repository stuff, since that works:

**api.ServerController**

```
package com.socie.backend.api;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.socie.backend.model.Response;
import com.socie.backend.service.implementation.ServerServiceImpl;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/server")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ServerController {
    private final ServerServiceImpl serverService;
    
    @GetMapping("/list")
    public  ResponseEntity<Response> getServers() throws InterruptedException {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(
                Response.builder()
                .timestamp(LocalDateTime.now())
                .data(Map.of("servers", serverService.list(30)))
                .message("Servers retrieved")
                .status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                .build()
        );
    }
}
```

**api.AuthenticationController**

```
package com.socie.backend.api;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.socie.backend.model.AuthenticationRequest;
import com.socie.backend.model.AuthenticationResponse;
import com.socie.backend.model.RegisterRequest;
import com.socie.backend.service.AuthenticationService;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationController {

    private final AuthenticationService authService;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> register(@RequestBody RegisterRequest request) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authService.register(request));
        
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> register(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest request) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authService.authenticate(request));
        
    }}
```

**service.AuthenticationService**

```
package com.socie.backend.service;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.socie.backend.config.JwtService;
import com.socie.backend.model.AuthenticationRequest;
import com.socie.backend.model.AuthenticationResponse;
import com.socie.backend.model.RegisterRequest;
import com.socie.backend.model.Role;
import com.socie.backend.model.User;
import com.socie.backend.repo.UserRepo;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationService {
    
    private final UserRepo userRepo;
    
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    private final JwtService jwtService;
    
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    public AuthenticationResponse register(RegisterRequest request) {

        var user = User.builder()
                .firstname(request.getFirstname())
                .lastname(request.getLastname())
                .email(request.getEmail())
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode(request.getPassword()))
                .role(Role.USER)
                .build();
        userRepo.save(user);
        
        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        return AuthenticationResponse.builder()
                .token(jwtToken)
                .build();
                
    }

public AuthenticationResponse authenticate(AuthenticationRequest request) {
    authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    request.getEmail(),
                    request.getPassword()
                    )
            );
    
    var user = userRepo.findByEmail(request.getEmail())
            .orElseThrow();
    
    var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
    return AuthenticationResponse.builder()
            .token(jwtToken)
            .build();
}

}
```

**config.ApplicationConfig**

```
package com.socie.backend.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import com.socie.backend.repo.UserRepo;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationConfig {

    private final UserRepo userRepo;
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> userRepo.findByEmail(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
        
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

**config.JwtAuthenticationFilter**

```
package com.socie.backend.config;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request, @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String userEmail;
        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            ;
            return;
        }

        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
        if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                        );
                authToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }
        
        filterChain.doFilter(request,  response);
    }

}
```

**config.JwtService**

```
import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.io.Decoders;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;

@Service
public class JwtService {

    private static final String SECRET_KEY = "ec9d2d0f7dd840b43cb0e52c189eb4c06c3b0307c2abf4c5aeef0d689ad12f19";
    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }
    
    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }
    
    public String generateToken(
            Map<String, Object> extraClaims,
            UserDetails userDetails)
    {
        return Jwts
                .builder()
                .setClaims(extraClaims)
                .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 24))
                .signWith(getSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }
    
    public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUsername(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }
    
    private boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    private Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        return generateToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails);
    }
    
    public Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.
                parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    private Key getSignInKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET_KEY);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }
}
```

**config.SecurityConfiguration**

```
package com.socie.backend.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/auth/**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
        .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter,  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
                
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: After a registration post to /auth/register the user is created properly in the database. I additionally tried annotating the AuthenticationServer with @Transactional but still I only get a 403 back.

Comment: Can i ask why you are building an insecure login that does not exist in spring security? You are aware that you cant logout your user and that jwts should not be handed out to browsers?

Comment: What does your own `User` object look like? How is the `UserDetails` interface being implemented?

Comment: @Toerktumlare What exactly is the problem with the jwts handed to the browser? I thought that was common practice.

Comment: First of all, you cant logout a user, because you cant invalidate a single jwt. Second of all, there is no way to stora a jwt securely in the browser. It is far from common practice. The common practice is to implement either session based login using cookies which is called `FormLogin` in spring security. Or implement the oauth2 flow called `Authorization Code flow with PKCE` every tutorial that hands out JWTs to browsers are written by developers that dont know how security works.

Comment: Do a little bit of thinking, why do you think that spring security a security library used by +10 000 applications, written by security experts, doesn’t have that implemented? There might be a good reason for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JWTService you are performing the following action

```
public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
    final String username = extractUsername(token);
    return (username.equals(userDetails) && !isTokenExpired(token));
}
```

should this instead be 'return username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())....' or similar.

Currently isTokenValid() will always return false as username is a String and userDetails is an object of type UserDetails. This would lead to 403 being returned on all endpoints validated with this method.